# ClickOnce installation does not find some files. But the app work fine in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, vsto, clickonce, office-addins

My [office VSTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/office-and-sharepoint-development-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#Add-ins) `add-in` works fine in `VS2019`. But when build it using [ClickOnce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) installation in `VS2019`, the installation of the `add-in` succeeds but when you click on a button on the add-in ribbon, it gives the following error. And when I manually check the below directory, the file indeed is not there. In `VS2019`, the `Build action` of the file is set to `None` and the `Copy to output directory` is set to `copy if newer`, but even if I change it to `always copy` it still is missing in the directory below. **Question**: Why the `ClickOnce` installation not copying this file to the directory below?

**Error**:

> > could not find the file: C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\XT2EMVW9.X5V\9NYY1LPL.G2A\offi..vsto_9bebe41ece21f852_0001.0000_7dfcd1fed25a3ae6\MyFile.xsl

Comment: When you test/debug VSTO addins in Visual Studio, it creates a temporary add-in for Excel.  To troubleshoot, start by opening Excel, go to the add-ins tab, click manage COM add-ins, and remove all versions of your add-in.  Don't just uncheck them, click the remove button.  Then close Excel and re-install your ClickOnce to begin troubleshooting.

Comment: try to include the file to publish application files-> project properties->publish->application file, set file "MyFile.xsl" Publish status to Include

Comment: @Naji I just followed your suggestion but noticed that the option ` project properties->publish->....` is not there. I'm using `VS2019`

Comment: @nam hmmm.. you are right , with vsto project you cannot select file(with winform you can) i'm looking into you question again, why you set Build action to "None" ? need to be "content", its will copy the file on publish...i have test it and its work